# Lack of outermost margin with smaller viewport

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a `<div id="wrapper"></div>​` with

```css
#wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
}​
```

When I resize the viewport so that horizontal scrollbars appear, the right margin disappears; I can only scroll as far right at the element's content, but I want the margin to be present on all sides. It also happens to the *left* margin if `right: 0;` is applied, and to the *bottom* margin if the viewport is made shorter. Giving `wrapper` a `position: static;` (default) makes no difference.

Why is this happening? It doesn't follow normal [margin collapse rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). How can I get my margin back? I've tried giving the body padding/margin.. nada.

- [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/QHKmN/)

Comment: I'm trying to understand, why not just set a `right: 10px`?

Comment: @OhMrBigshot It has no effect. Please demonstrate on the jsFiddle. I'd like to have an outermost element, none of whose margins collapse due to viewport resizing...

Comment: Try Position:relative, it will make your margin present on all side even after resize.

Comment: @MSUH not seeing it http://jsfiddle.net/QHKmN/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background Info

The default width of the `body` element is the `html` width which is also the window width (or `iframe` width in such a case). The default behavior of a block level element is that the scroll only accounts for the actual element (hence, it doesn't care about the right margin if there is nothing more to display on the right). This causes your right margin issue. (By the way, according to [this article](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html), the scroll bars are actually appearing on the html element, not the body.)

### For `Position: Absolute`

By having `#wrapper` with `position: absolute`, the `body` element ends up with zero height. This causes your bottom margin issue in this case.

**A solution** is to account for the margins like so ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARf8x/9/)):

```
body {
    min-height: 320px;
    min-width: 420px; 
}
```

This assigns a minimum dimension to the `body` equal to the width + margins and height + margins of the absolute element.

Now, I'm not sure what you expect to happen if you have `right: 0` set, as forcing a left margin to "remain" just ends up causing, in my opinion, a premature scroll bar to activate. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARf8x/10/).

### Regarding `Position: Static`

The default block level behavior can be changed by forcing a shrink-wrap like behavior on the body element using ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARf8x/14/)):

```
body { display: inline-block; }
```

Note: that `body { float: left; }` did not give me the same shrink-wrap behavior ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARf8x/16/)).

The `inline-block` element will account for the margin of its inner elements to determine its own width, which then allows the right margin to work.

The reason the `display: inline-block;` solution does not work on the `#wrapper` being `position: absolute` is because it makes the `body` have a zero width and height, since the absolute positioning takes that element out of flow and there is nothing left inside `body` to give it dimension.

***The above was currently only tested on IE9.***

Comment: great answer, will bounty when possible. This came up because the wrapper element had a box shadow that was stylistically desirable, and it was not visible on two sides when viewport shrunk. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's only one simple and quick solution, and that is to create a new div inside the wrapper div.

http://jsfiddle.net/QHKmN/2/

CSS

```css
#wrapper {
    background: black;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
}

#inwrapper {
    background: green;
    height: 290px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 390px;
}
​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inwrapper">

    </div>
</div>
​
```

And there's your margin.